# C# DataGridView binding to dynamic data

Tags: c#, dynamic, binding, datagridview

I want to create an application that is refreshing DataGridView content with data about surrounding Wifi networks on every second. I wonder what would be the best binding solution for this task. I think using BindingList is meaningless, because it would update the datagridview on every single update on the List, while it would be better to refresh it after whole List is updated. Meaby simple List and rebinding is appropriate here, what do you think?

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the DataGridView from updating on every change to your BindingList by the following

```
myBindingList.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;
// Update BindingList
myBindingList.RaiseListChangedEvents = true;
myBindingList.ResetBindings();
```

The ResetBindings() call will cause your DataGridView to be refreshed to reflect the changes to myBindingList.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I just wonder if it would be better for this situation to use BindingList or meaby simple rebinding DataSource to updated list or something completely different.